# How to search something in the Database independent of the sequence of words?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am working on a search filter that connects to a MySQL database. It accepts a keyword parameter; however, it only searches for the keyword in the order it is typed in. For example: If I type in "house rental", it looks for the term in xyz column in the order it is typed it.

However, I would like to change it so that it searches for both those terms are independent of the order they are typed in. Example, if typed in "house rental", the result should contain listings that have either, "house rental" or "rental house" mentioned somewhere in the xyz columns.

I have tried to break the keywords, put it in an array and do a foreach loop on the array to get the result but it generates correct but undesired results. The results that are generated are not the ones that I required.

```
$samp_text = 'House Rental';
$split_string_array = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $samp_text);
foreach ($split_string_array as $each_sql_query) {
    print_r('SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE $keyword LINK = %' . $each_sql_query . '% '. "\r");
}
```

I would like a suggestion on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Use `LIKE` or `REGEXP_LIKE()`. Either that or do a redesign for `FULLTEXT` searches.

Comment: Do the keywords need to be adjacent as in your question, or are you just looking to see if either or both are in the text? If you just waant to find the rows that contain both, that is easily accomplished by using the **%** wildcard character. Use a for loop the build the WHERE clause, then execute a single query,

Answer (score 0):

While the method Sloan Thrasher suggests works, it does not scale.

The solution is to create a table contains each keyword from a searchable document as a single row with a foreign key to the original document with an index on the search word then the foreign key. Split your search term into an equivalent table, join the 2 and count the matches:

```
Select doc.txt, count(*)
From doc
Inner join keywords
On doc.id=keywords.doc_id
Inner join search
On keywords.word=search.word
Where search.query_id=?
Group by doc.txt
Order by count(*) desc
```

Alternatively just use the [built-in fulltext](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) capability of mysql.

Answer (score -1):

You can build a query that will check for all keywords at once and give you list of rows that contain all of the keywords.

If you want all rows that contain one or more keywords, change the **AND** in the implode function to **OR**.

```
$samp_text = 'House Rental';
$split_string_array = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $samp_text);
$qstr = "SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE ";
$keywords = array();
foreach ($split_string_array as $each_sql_query) {
    $keywords[] = " LINK = '%" . $each_sql_query . "%'\r")
}
$qstr .= implode(" AND ",$keywords);

//  Code to execute query and use results.
```